# What's wrong with this code? I have to add 2 to find out the original answer?

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, append, finance

I want to find out **Payback time period** using **R**. So I followed a python code and tried to turn it over to R. But, the answer I get, is always 2 less than the right answer.

I have tried adding 2, this is just a simple hack. But, the main problem is still there.

```
cashInflows     <-  data.frame( 
    Year        =   c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
    ProjectA    =   c(10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 20000), 
    ProjectB    =   c(40000, 30000, 20000, 10000, 20000)
    ) 
total       =   0
years       =   0
cumulative  <-  c()

for (f in cashInflows$ProjectB){
    total       =   f + total
    if (total   < cashOutflows){
        years = years + 1
    cumulative <-   append(cumulative, total)
   }
}

A  <- years - 1
B  <- cashOutflows - cumulative[years]
C  <- cashInflows$ProjectB[years + 2] # Why +2 ???????? ( I don't know specifically yet.)
print (A + (B/C))
```

Comment: What should the data look like after transformation?

Comment: `Error in cashOutflows : object 'cashOutflows' not found`.

Comment: You have not defined cashOutflows in you for loop statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some working code with a few modifications.

1) As others have noted, you need to define `cashOutflows` somewhere for this to run.

2) R uses 1-based indexing, so you won't get what you expect if you ever have code that accesses the 0th index of a vector. I've changed `years` to start with 1, so that if the incrementing loop is never called (i.e. we pass breakeven inside of Year 1), we will get a valid number (0) instead of NULL.

I've put the code inside a function called `test`, which takes `cashOutflows` as its input.

```
total       =   0
years       =   1
cumulative  <-  0

test <- function(cashOutflows) {
  for (f in cashInflows$ProjectB){
    total       =   f + total
    if (total   < cashOutflows){
      years = years + 1
      cumulative <-   append(cumulative, total)
    }
  }

  A  <- years - 1
  B  <- cashOutflows - cumulative[years]
  C  <- cashInflows$ProjectB[years] 
  return (A + (B/C))
}
```

We can then try this function out with a few inputs, which produce the outputs I would have expected:

```
> as.numeric(lapply(c(20000, 39999, 40000, 40001, 70000, 80000), test))
[1] 0.500000 0.999975 1.000000 1.000033 2.000000 2.500000
```

This tells us that when we feed 20k into `test`, we get 0.5, since that's half of the first year inflow of 40k. When we feed 39.999k into the function, we get a breakeven time of 0.9999 years, since we don't need quite a whole year of 40k to break even.

---

Arguably, something like the approach below would be more idiomatic for R, where we use a built-in vectorized function like `cumsum`.

```
cashOutflows <- 70000
output <- cashInflows
output$cuml = cumsum(output$ProjectB)       # Add column with cumulative total
output$excess = output$cuml - cashOutflows  # Calc "excess" over breakeven
output <- subset(output, excess >= 0)[1, ]  # Select first year at or beyond breakeven
output$Breakeven = output$Year - output$excess/output$ProjectB
output$Breakeven
```